# Ionic 404 HTTP request on device

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 3 app working with the Youtube Data API. I have a `GET` request to return playlists from a channeI ID. It works fine in the browser but I get `404` from the compiled app in and Android Device.

```
getVideos(channel) {
   return this.http.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=${this.apiKey}&channelId=${channel}&part=snippet,id&maxResults=20`)
              .map(res => {
                return res.json()['items'];
              })
  }
```

I've set the API key in my `config.xml` as well.

```
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="YouTubeDataApiKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXX MY KEY XXXXXXXX" />
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure your parameters are properly inserted in the URL? HTTP 404 implies a response from the server, so I think there is no problem about the configuration, otherwise, the request wouldn't even happen.

Comment: @sjahan I'm certain they are as the same request works well in the browser, even if I follow the 404 link returned in the browser console when I debug the app via USB

Comment: that's very weird, because as you probably know, 404 suggests it is a client error because the URL passed is not mapped to any resource...
Could there be some cache or a cookie remaining in your browser that wouldn't be in your device?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with params passed into URL.

Build your string like this to add parameter value :

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=' + ${this.apiKey} + '&channelId=' + ${channel} + '&part=snippet,id&maxResults=20'
```